# How to create an edit text using Relative Layout programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a new edit text in java code based on the old one, which I've created through XML. I want this new edit text to appear to the right hand side of the old edit text and below the image view, which I've also created in XML, and I use RelativeLayout for this:

```
private void createEditText(){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            editText.getLayoutParams().width,
            editText.getLayoutParams().height);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, editText.getId());
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
    final EditText newEditText = new EditText(this);
    newEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_edittext);
    newEditText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    relativeLayout.addView(newEditText);
}
```

But the new edit text appears on the top of the screen, ignoring addRule function, which I've used in the code. Here is the RealtiveLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a mistake in java code or in XML file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to call `setLayoutParams` after `addView`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set an index for the newEditText.
the default is -1, that means it will be added before the other views.
you can get the amount of children with `relativeLayout.getChildCount();`
since the count is the amount of children it is also the correct index for adding the `newEditText`.

```
private void createEditText(){
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        editText.getLayoutParams().width,
        editText.getLayoutParams().height);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, editText.getId());
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
final EditText newEditText = new EditText(this);
newEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_edittext);

relativeLayout.addView(newEditText,relativeLayout.getChildCount(),layoutParams);
}
```

and since you made the `newEditText` final keep in mind that you can't use this method more than once everytime you start up the app.